# True vs predicted scatter plot for categorical data

Tags: r, scatter-plot, prediction, scatter

I want a scatter plot that shows the comparison between true vs predicted for categorical data. The data is in a dataframe. The data looks like this:

```
 predicted true
1         3    3
2         2    2
3         3    2
4         2    2
5         3    2
6         2    2
```

dput(tr2[5,]) gives

```
structure(list(predicted = 3, true = 2), row.names = 5L, class = "data.frame")
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: you showed only a single observation in `dput` and those are factor columns

Comment: Try with `pairs(tr2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape the data in long format before plotting -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, value, color = name)) + geom_point()
```